# Bluetooth headphones no longer pairing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth, device-manager, wireless-headset

My Bluetooth headphones used to pair with no issues on my Windows 7 x64 installation until yesterday. Whenever I turn on my headphones, it shows up as “Standard Serial over Bluetooth Link (COM21)” in the Device and Printers window. This is the only Bluetooth peripheral I have installed on this desktop machine. The dongle is a [Asus USB-BT400](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/USBBT400/) and the headphones are the [LG HB 750](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/763243/Lg-Hbs-750.html). The Asus USB-BT400 uses the Bluetooth 4.0 standard.

I’ve tried reinstalling the WIDCOMM drivers a few times, but that hasn’t helped. I’ve also tried removing the BT ENUM keys in the registry before reinstalling the WIDCOMM drivers, and that hasn’t helped either. I also tried repairing my headphones with the BT adapter, but the head phones do not appear when I go to the ”Add Blue tooth Devices” window. The adapter does not show my head phones for pairing, even though it is in pairing mode.

One interesting thing is that the dongle does pick up other Bluetooth devices, such as my printer.

Does anyone know how to get the Bluetooth software to recognize my head phones again?

Here is a screenshot of the windows mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the battery in the headphones?  Are you sure the headphone Bluetooth is enabled?

Check with a separate BT device that it can connect to the headphones.

Comment: Have you attempted a System Restore to a date prior to yesterday, when they did work?

Comment: @Daniel. I checked the batteries and they are fully charged. I tried a different blue tooth head phone and it could not connect.

Comment: @CharlieRB I used a System Restore point from Monday and it's working again. No idea what caused it to stop recognizing the head phone.

Answer (score 0):

I used a System Restore point from earlier in the week and it's recognizing the head phones again. No idea what caused it to stop recognizing the head phones.